# authority_not_in_valid_list: 'authority' is not in the list of valid addresses

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, active-directory, access-token

I am trying to call a Authenticated API from my client app. However, when making **AcquireTokenAsync**, I get following error "***authority_not_in_valid_list: 'authority' is not in the list of valid addresses***"

here is my code snippet:

```
resourceUrl = "https://myApiEndPoint.com";

var clientCredential =
     new ClientCredential( myClientAppId, myClientSecretKey );
```

// myClientAppId and myClientSecretKey are the values from Azure Portal

```
var authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext( "https://my_authority/myApiEndPoint");

return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync( resourceUrl, clientCredential );
```

In my azure Portal for my client Id of app, I have granted delegated permission to access https://myApiEndPOint.com api.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this issue and what does it mean by not in valid list?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that:

- you created your application in the Azure portal, and therefore the authority is the Azure AD endpoint. Therefore the authority is probably https://login.microsoftonline.com/common? Or do you have good reasons to use "https://my_authority" ?
- you have granted *delegated permissions* to access the API. This means that your application will access the API in the name of the user. However the AcquireTokenAsync method that you use is using the "ClientCredential" flow (meaning with an application secret)
  You probably rather want to use another override passing the resourceUri, the clientId, ...

If this is your use case, I suggest you have a look to the [active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) sample (See [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListClient/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L88))